# AsyncTask NullPointerException after two rotates with listfragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

I have an app that works with LisFragment and ViewPagerIndicator. When the screen rotates twice, the app gives the error that the logcat attached.
My problem seems to be related to the context is null. I have seen several issues here on StackOverflow but I have not managed to solve it. Seems I have to implement the methods onAttach and onDetach but not as as what I have tried has failed.

Please can you help me. I'm frankly desperate with this issue.

Thanks.

My LogCat

```
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:271)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:150)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at es.app.adeptlabel.AdaptadorList.<init>(AdaptadorList.java:27)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at es.app.adeptlabel.ArtFragment$CreateArrayListTaskArt.onPostExecute(ArtFragment.java:63)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at es.app.adeptlabel.ArtFragment$CreateArrayListTaskArt.onPostExecute(ArtFragment.java:1)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 08:30:18.939: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 08:30:19.099: E/Buffer Error(602): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
```

My class that inherits from ListFragment

```
public class RlsFragment extends ListFragment{


Activity mActivity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // normally you should inflate a view here and save references
// using ListFragment default layout for this example
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
new CreateArrayListTaskRls().execute();
}


private class CreateArrayListTaskRls extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList <ElementosList>> {


    protected ArrayList <ElementosList> doInBackground(String...strings)
    {
        ArrayList <ElementosList> itemRls = new ArrayList <ElementosList>();
        itemRls.clear();
        loadDataJsonRls();
        for(int i=0;i<ListViewConfig.getResim_list_txt().size();i++)
        {
            itemRls.add(new ElementosList(ListViewConfig.getResim_list_txt().get(i),
                    ListViewConfig.getResim_list_img().get(i)));
        }       
        return itemRls;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList <ElementosList> itemsRls) {
        ArrayAdapter<ElementosList>adaptadorRls = new AdaptadorList(getActivity(),itemsRls);
        setListAdapter(adaptadorRls);                  
    }

    }//fin createArraylistTask

.
.
.
.
.
.
```

La clase AdaptadorList

```
public class AdaptadorList extends ArrayAdapter<ElementosList> {

Activity contexto;
private ArrayList<ElementosList> elementos;

AdaptadorList(Activity contexto, ArrayList<ElementosList> elementos)
{       
    super(contexto,R.layout.opciones,elementos);
    this.elementos = elementos;
    this.contexto = contexto;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
{
    View item = convertView;
    final VistaTag vistaTag;
    if(item==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = contexto.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opciones, null);
        vistaTag = new VistaTag();
        vistaTag.titulo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        vistaTag.imgadpt = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        item.setTag(vistaTag);          
    }
    else
    {
        vistaTag = (VistaTag)item.getTag();
    }
    //Aplicacion fuente verdana
    Typeface verdana = Typeface.createFromAsset(contexto.getAssets(), "verdana.ttf");

    vistaTag.titulo.setText(elementos.get(position).getTitulo());
    vistaTag.titulo.setTypeface(verdana);
    vistaTag.imgadpt.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(elementos.get(position).getImagen()));

    return(item);

}//fin getView
```

Comment: Attempted read on closed stream - so you are trying to read closed stream (probably when you are reading JSON from Server).

Comment: error is in postexecute()
debug it and find out what is null into it.
check for not null before doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usual problem of fragments and AsyncTask. It is caused by AsyncTask completes it is work in the moment then view of fragment doesn't exist. If you use AsyncTask with fragment always check that view of the fragment is available. The better way is to use loaders.

This could fix your code:

```
private class CreateArrayListTaskRls extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList <ElementosList>> {


protected ArrayList <ElementosList> doInBackground(String...strings)
{
    ArrayList <ElementosList> itemRls = new ArrayList <ElementosList>();
    itemRls.clear();
    loadDataJsonRls();
    for(int i=0;i<ListViewConfig.getResim_list_txt().size();i++)
    {
        itemRls.add(new ElementosList(ListViewConfig.getResim_list_txt().get(i),
                ListViewConfig.getResim_list_img().get(i)));
    }       
    return itemRls;
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList <ElementosList> itemsRls) {
    ArrayAdapter<ElementosList>adaptadorRls = new AdaptadorList(getActivity(),itemsRls);
    if (getListView() != null) {        
       setListAdapter(adaptadorRls);                  
    }
}

}//fin createArraylistTask
```

Comment: How do I call listview? I do not have it physically in the layout. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I see you use ListFragment so change to getListView().

Comment: The problem is that the Context is null when the screen rotates twice. Thanks for the help Oknesif.

Comment: There do you use Context? Try to use getActivity().getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList <ElementosList> itemsRls) {
   if (getListView() != null) {  ArrayAdapter<ElementosList>adaptadorRls = new AdaptadorList(getActivity(),itemsRls);           
   setListAdapter(adaptadorRls);                  
}
}
```

Thanks to everyone. Thanks Oknesif.